# Raspberry PI 4: Control RPI.GPIO pins through dictionary keys

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to control GPIO pins through dictionary pins:
My code:

```
var gpio = require('onoff').Gpio;
var rpi_board = [{'pin_17_in':new gpio(17,'in')},
                 {'pin_27_in':new gpio(27,'in')},
                 {'pin_19_out':new gpio(19,'out')},
                 {'pin_26_out':new gpio(26,'out')}];

var outputChannels = [
    { physicalPin: rpi_board.pin_19_out, pin:19, location:"EntraceLight", meter: "EntraceLightON", active:true, device_id:2 },
    { physicalPin: rpi_board.pin_26_out, pin:26, location:"BackdoorLight", meter: "BackdoorLightON", active:true, device_id:3 }
];
console.log("Set outputChannels[0] to high: ")
console.log(outputChannels[0].physicalPin.writeSync(1))
```

Present output:

```
'Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property \'writeSync\' of undefined'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'writeSync' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to create one dictionary instead of 4 inside an array

```
var rpi_board = {
  'pin_17_in':new gpio(17,'in'),
  'pin_27_in':new gpio(27,'in'),
  'pin_19_out':new gpio(19,'out'),
  'pin_26_out':new gpio(26,'out')
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But each pin has a got a unique information, so I created one dictionary for each PIN inside a list as in `outputChannels`. Question is, how do I set a specific PIN in this list high or low?

Comment: The other parts of the code are correct. The problem is that `rpi_board.pin_19_out` is `undefined` hence later `outputChannels[0].physicalPin.writeSync(1)` throws an error

Comment: You are correct. I just noticed it. Here is the correct initialization `physicalPin: rpi_board[2].pin_19_out` and now I see LED glow with this `outputChannels[1].physicalPin.writeSync(1)`. Thanks